# K nearest neighbour estimation example

Tags: estimation, k-nearest-neighbour

I want to know how the k–Nearest-Neighbor Estimation work. for example i want to classify test sample (0.5, 0) in Unbiased K Nearest Neighbor approximation with k = 3, and Euclidean distance: $d(,)= √Σi(−)^2$ for two classes.

I have two-dimensional training samples from two classes like below

[image: two-dimensional training samples from two classes]

how should i use the  $$f(x) = K-1 / QV$$
what is Q here? and where should i use this given Euclidean distance in formula, without formula it's obvious that i should compare the test sample with 3 near points then the test sample would be in class which has the maximum member around it.

Comment: where do you see the formula?

Comment: Pattern classification, Duda

Comment: Hi, can you be more precise, which page of Duda? the formula has $x$ on the lef hand side but I don't see it ont he right.

Comment: It's in chapter 4, page 18, but it's the bias formula, the unbiased is the one i mentioned before